# How to do a dataset.Merge using .getXML instead of .Merge

Tags: .net, xml, ado.net, dataset

So I have been having trouble getting dataset.Merge to work right, it does not seem to want to append records from identically named and schema'd datatables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124504/cannot-get-dataset-merge-to-work for that issue.

I found a workaround using GetXML which I will now answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Merge the XML from your datasets:
tempXML &= Dataset1.GetXML()
tempXML &= Dataset2.GetXML()
' Remove the root tags from the XML I used <FullRecord> for mine
tempXML = tempXML.Replace("<FullRecord>", "").Replace("</FullRecord>", "")
' Make a new dataset with the modified XML. Be sure to put root tag back first
MergedDS = New DataSet
rdr = New StringReader("<FullRecord>" & tempXML & "</FullRecord>")
MergedDS.ReadXml(rdr)
```

The new `MergedDS` will have all of your tables and the same named tables will have their records combined. I have only tested it on my rather complex datasets (4 and 15 tables respectively with relationships and other constraints.)